# Create an updatable view

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, insert-update

I am using postgres9.1 and I have been struggling a lot to find some tutorials on how to create a view which can be later be updated and new rows can be inserted in the view.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to do a view which is updatable and can accept the insertion of new rows?

Comment: Use an `instead of` trigger: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html or see here: http://vibhorkumar.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/instead-of-trigger/

Answer (score 2):

Updateable views are somewhat complicated.  There are two ways to do them, one with RULEs and one with TRIGGERs.  Triggers pose more performance problems while RULEs pose more subtle coding gotchas.  I will cover both approaches here.

Suppose I have a base table and a view which provides access to a portion of the base table:

```
CREATE TABLE mybase (
      id serial primary key,
      type_id int not null,
      payload text not null
 );

 CREATE VIEW type1 AS select * from mybase WHERE type_id = 1;
```

Ok, simple enough.  Now we want to make the view updateable.  The old way (maintenance gotchas) is to use rules:

```
 CREATE RULE on_insert AS ON insert TO type1 
 DO INSTEAD INSERT into mybase(id, type_id, payload) VALUES (new.id, 1, payload);

 CREATE RULE on_update AS ON update TO type1
 DO INSTEAD UPDATE mybase set payload = new.payload where id = old.id;
```

Now this will work but with a few caveats.  The first is that if I:

```
 INSERT INTO type1 (id, type_id, payload) values (DEFAULT, 2, 'foo');
```

It will instead silently enter 1 instead of 2.  That may not be desirable.  You can make your code more complex or you can call a function to do your inserts and updates, but RULEs have the advantage of being parsed into query at plan time, and functions will be run once per row, so an update that updates a million rows will perform FAR better with simple rules than with functions.  Getting the rules right is complex and tricky but it means that updates to the views will scale up in the way that writes to the updates to the base tables will.

If you have multiple tables, however things get far more complicated because you have update or delete multiple rows and because this gets merged in at planning time (rather than per row) one side may get deleted and then the other side may not be able to find what needs to be deleted.  But if you go functions then you have write scaling problems with deletes and updates (which basically ties you into repeated index scan loops).

The other option is to use triggers.  Triggers are functions which get called for each row being written and hence they have the write scaling issues of rules calling functions.   With this approach we'd create trigger functions and create triggers on the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION type1_trigger_func() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS 
$$
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
     IF new.type_id <> 1 THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid type!'; END IF;
     insert into mybasetable (id, type_id, payload) 
     VALUES (new.id, new.type_id, new.payload);
     RETURN NEW;
  ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
     IF new.type_id <> 1 THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid type!'; END IF;
     -- update statement goes here
     RETURN NEW;
  ELSIF TG_IP = 'DELETE' THEN
     DELETE FROM mybasetable WHERE id = old.id;
     RETURN OLD;
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

Then we create triggers:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER make_updateable INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON TYPE1
 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE type1_trigger_func();
```

In general the difficulties with RULEs and TRIGGERs in this context has made me lean towards stored procedures instead of views.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Views to Update Data**
A view can be used in a query that updates data, subject to a few restrictions. Bear in mind that a view is not a table and contains no data—the actual modification always takes place at the table level. Views cannot be used as a mechanism to override any constraints, rules, or referential integrity defined in the base tables.

**Restrictions on Updating Data Through Views**
You can insert, update, and delete rows in a view, subject to the following limitations:

If the view contains joins between multiple tables, you can only insert and update one table in the view, and you can't delete rows.

You can't directly modify data in views based on union queries. You can't modify data in views that use GROUP BY or DISTINCT statements.

All columns being modified are subject to the same restrictions as if the statements were being executed directly against the base table.

Text and image columns can't be modified through views.